# how to save the same object type in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I want to save the same object type in an `Array()`

For example when I want to select all checkboxes and save the value in an Array:

```
selectAllCbs: function() {
            var self = this;
            $('#' + instanceName + 'table_form input[type=checkbox]').each(function(index,cb) {
                if($(cb).prop('disabled') == false) {
                    $(cb).prop('checked',true);
                    console.log("Select all clicked:" + cb); //gives me [object HTMLInputElement] result
                    selected.push(cb); //save to an array
                    self.changeRowStyle(cb);
                }
            });
```

When I use almost the same code when user clicks on the row I'm getting different type:

```
rowClicked: function(id) {
        var cb = $('#' + instanceName + 'cb_' + id);

        if($(cb).is(':checked')) {
            $(cb).prop('checked',false);
            selected.splice(selected.indexOf(this.value),1);
        } else {
            $(cb).prop('checked',true);
            console.log("Row clicked:" + cb); //gives me [object Object]
            selected.push(cb);
        }
        this.changeRowStyle(cb);
    },
```

So the main question is how to save the rowClicked element in the `[object HTMLInputElement]` type?

Because in the first example I can read values with `selected[i].value` and with the second one I need to read it with the `selected[i][0].value`.

Comment: `"Select all clicked:" + cb` ...really !?...

Comment: @Virus721 whats wrong with that? That was just for testing purposes...

Comment: selected.push($(cb)[0]);

Comment: @dcodesmith in the `select all` or in the `row clicked`?

Comment: The question is: do you want to save the jquery object $(cb) or the DOM element cb ?  Here `var cb = $('#' + instanceName + 'cb_' + id);` cb is a jquery object, a DOM element wrapped with jquery functions

Comment: @roasted I want to save the second code in this type `[object HTMLInputElement]`, I need to be able to save the savme values when clicked on any

Comment: So, to return an DOM element of a jquery array-like object, use its index: '[0]' or `.get(0)`

Comment: @roasted where to put that? you know you can write and answer and get some points if you know it

Comment: @user123_456 `row_clicked`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `rowClicked`, replace:

```
selected.push(cb);
```

With:

```
selected.push(cb[0]);
```

And do the same in `rowClicked` for `this.changeRowStyle(cb[0])` method

Comment: He shouldn't need to do the same for the `changeRowStyle` method as the value passed from the each JQuery method is a Dom element. It hasn't been wrapped in the JQuery logic.

Comment: @shennan in rowclicked, he need to use `this.changeRowStyle(cb[0])` as here cb is a jquery object

Comment: My apologies, I thought you meant change it in the `selectAllCbs` method, which is already a DOM element. Hence I mentioned the `each` JQuery method.

Answer (score 1):

What may be confusing you is the comparison of your array elements at a later stage. You cannot compare two JQuery objects, but you *can* compare two DOM Elements.

JQuery wraps everything up as a JQuery object in order to super-charge it with all that sexy functionality. What you are storing in the first lot of code is a DOM element, because you don't wrap `cb` in the JQuery selector method. In the second lot of code, you're storing a JQuery selector.

In order to get the DOM element for the second lot of code, simply use the `get` method at the end of your `rowClicked` function:

```
this.changeRowStyle(cb.get(0));
```

And, obviously, change your push arguments for this function to be the same:

```
selected.push(cb.get(0));
```